# How to Add next and back arrows to jquery image slider?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have created a jquery slider that works great on autoplay but i am facing difficulty in the jquery of next and previous buttons.

HTML is

```
<div id="slider">
<div>
<img src="slideshow/Chrysanthemum.jpg"  width="500" height="300"></img>
 </div>
<div>
<img src="slideshow/Tulips.jpg" title="Tulips" width="500" height="300"></img>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="left-arrow">
<img src="images/left.png"></img>
</div>
  <div class="right-arrow">
  <img src="images/right.png"></img>
</div>
```

and jquery is

```
$(function() {

        $("#slider > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slider > div:first')
            .fadeIn(2500)
            .next()
            .fadeOut(2500)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slider');
        },  2500);

        next(function(){
        $('.right-arrow').click(function(){
        $("#slider > div:first")
        .fadeIn(500)
       .next()
       .fadeOut(500)
       .end()
       .appendTo("#slider");            
         }, 500);
        });

        previous(function(){
        $('.left-arrow').click(function(){
        $("#slider > div:last")
        .fadeOut(500)
       .prev()
       .fadeIn(500)
       .end()
       .appendTo("#slider");            
         }, 500);
        });
        });
```

Slideshow works in autoplay but next and previous arrows doesn't work. What's wrong am i doing in jquery? Please Help

Comment: Why  are you wrapping the event handlers in functions ?

Comment: please also provide css code

Comment: This might not be what you want to here nor is it an answer. But you should consider using a jquery plugin or another javascript library for a slideshow.

Al you have now are a couple of jquery lines. Don't get me wrong but building a good slideshow is nothing you can do on a weekend.

Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/. Maybe this is a plugin that suits your needs.

Comment: Suggestion

I think if you use a active class for active image, will be more helpful, Since you will dependence of this class to next or prev image, also you can do more when you add this class for real active slider..I think its will be resolved your problem .